# Creating an RSA PKCS1 v1.5 key

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create an RSA PKCS v1.5 key from a modulus and exponent, this is how far I got:

```
BigInteger mod = BigInteger.Parse(loginData["publickey_mod"], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
BigInteger exp = BigInteger.Parse(loginData["publickey_exp"], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
string timestamp = loginData["timestamp"];
string steamid = loginData["steamid"];

RSAParameters loginRSA = new RSAParameters();
loginRSA.Modulus = mod.ToByteArray();
loginRSA.Exponent = exp.ToByteArray();
```

However after searching the web for quite some times (>1 hour) I couldn't find anyway to create an RSA key... I need to create one to encode a password. Is there anyone that could help me a little further?

Comment: This looks like a next step https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.importparameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yeh checked it out. I got a little further, ill edit the question to as far as I managed to get when i'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the RSAParameters of the public key information then just import it directly into an RSA instance:

```
using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    // Import public key
    rsa.ImportParameters(loginRSA);

    // Encrypt some data
    var cipherText = rsa.EncryptValue(someData);
}
```